# Renaming multiple files with multiple names

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr, stringr

```
setwd("C:\\Users\\...\\Documents\\Main\\eml orders") 

files <- list.files(pattern="*.eml")

newfiles <- gsub(".eml$", ".txt", files)

file.rename(files, newfiles)

eml_files <- list.files(pattern = "txt$")
```

I have this code to convert .eml into .txt files now I want to rename the same files into a string that i make with a function.

Example of function

```
fetch_date <- function(x) {
date <- paste0(as.character(Sys.time()), ".txt")
file.rename(x, date)
}
```

Now I try `map(eml_files, fetch_date)`

And get this error:

```
cannot rename file '24 New order placed.txt' to '2020-11-14', reason 'The network path was not found'
```

No clue what's happening any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You may need `full.names = TRUE` in `list.files`

Comment: Same error :/ .

Comment: Inside the function, you may need to specify the path with `file.path`

Comment: i did `file.path("C:\\Users\\...\\Documents\\Main\\eml orders")` inside the function and its still not working. throws the same errors.

Comment: It seems that your file.rename is working outside the function.  Have you tried the second set of renaming without the function

Comment: Gives me the same error:

`test_rename <- fetch_date(eml_files[1])`
`file.rename(eml_files[1], test_rename)`

used `file.rename` outside of the function and still doesn't work

Comment: Yes it works if i just set the rename to `"test_rename.txt"`

Comment: With the date rename, I didn't find any suffix `.txt`

Comment: As an exercise, I would test first with a manual string rename with the date and check if that works with the full path.  Also, because the working directory is already set, the path shouldn't be a problem

Comment: The `paste` should be `paste0(as.character(Sys.date()), ".txt")` as `paste` creates a space `" "`

Comment: My code does have `.txt` pasted onto the end of the string and ive updated the body of the question thanks for pointing it out

Comment: same error even if its `paste0`

Comment: You have your current file in `files` and the new name in `newfiles`. What is `date <- paste0(as.character(Sys.date()), ".txt")` used for? Can you show few names of your original files and what name would you like them to be renamed to?

Comment: `24 New order placed.txt` is the name of one of the files and keep in mind its not one file its 15 different files that I'm assigning the date to individually with a string, The date object is just for use inside the function it just fetches the date and turns it into a string and i want to change the file name to the date string assigned to the `date` variable

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that your `fetch_date` function only outputs one string (`Sys.date()`). It tries to name several `.txt` objects with the same name. On my mac, this results in the last files getting kept while the others are overwritten. Perhaps you use Windows and there is another default behavior when files are overwritten?

```
eml_files <- list.files(pattern = "txt$")


fetch_date <- function(x) {
  date <- paste0(as.character(Sys.time()), ".txt")
  file.rename(x, date)
}


map(eml_files, fetch_date)
```

[image]

[image]